# How can iid be from a conditional distribution?

Tags: probability

Could someone explain to me how the following two things can hold at the same time:

(a)  $y$ is conditionally distributed to depend on $x$, that is $f(y|x)$
(b)  $y$ is also i.i.d. (independent of $x$) 
?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: i.i.d. stands for Independent and Identically Distributed and it is used for more than one random variables (such as random vectors or random processes). So,a random variable being i.i.d. is meaningless. maybe (b) is $y$ is independent of $x$? if so there are lots of p.d.f.'s that are so. For example: $$ f(x,y)=xy \qquad,\qquad 0 \leq x,y \leq \sqrt2 $$

Comment: Dear Mahdi, Thank you.  So it can be the case that $f(y|x)$ is dependent of $x$ but $y$ is an i.i.d. process which is independent of $x$?

Comment: Being i.i.d. is only defined for many random variables. So, $f(y|x)$ could be only a function of $y$ (and not a function of $x$)..

Comment: So if y was a vector of many random variables, distributed in a p.d.f. that is conditional on x, it is also possible to have the many ys be i.i.d. across another vector of many xs?

Comment: if you mean random vector $y$ being independent of random vector $x$ It may be possible, I don't have any examples.

Comment: Could you explain (a) and (b)? At present, neither makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

An example: $$ f(x,y)=xy \qquad,\qquad 0 \leq x,y \leq \sqrt2 $$